# How can I save values produced in a for loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, int

I am trying to save the factors of a number(d) as integers so I can use them later in my code. Any suggestions on how I can do this?

```
for (i = 1; i <= d; i++) {
      if (d % i == 0) {
    System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ever consider storing in a `List`?

Comment: Has your class looked at any data structures, such as arrays or lists?

Comment: Read about arrays or lists. Also turn to the [help] to learn how and what to ask here.

Comment: Refer to the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/) to learn about variables, variable scope, and [collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in a for loop, when declaring the temp variable "i" you need to declare it as int i = 1; instead of "i = 1" I assume you already have a value for the variable d but in this case, I just used d = 123.

```
       int  d = 123;    
        for (int i = 1; i <= d; i++) 
        {
            if (d % i == 0) 
                System.out.print(i + " ");
        }

Output: 
1 3 41 123
```

In the case you want to store them and use it later in your code, there are many things you can use such as ArrayList, Queue, Stack, etc.

I used a stack here:

```
    Stack<Integer> intStack = new Stack<>();
    int d = 123;
    for (int i = 1; i <= d; i++) 
    {
        if (d % i == 0) 
        {
            intStack.push(i);
        }
    }
    while (!intStack.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println(intStack.pop());
    }
```